# File Handling Alternative in Java

Tags: java, file-handling

I was wondering does java provides any way to implement programs stated below without file handling.

Lets say I want to make a program for hospital patients record or a phonebook in which I can add, delete and edit patient name, NIC number and phone number.. Making such a program with file handling will be difficult.

I know its a stupid question but I am new to Java..

Regards

Comment: isn't a database an internet thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a database. A database helps you store, retrieve and modify data. It usually does a better job than you (or me) ever will implementing this with files. A database is not strictly for use online, you can just install one on your local machine.

`JBDC` is a term you should use for googling

Comment: Can you link me to some video tutorials for JBDC?

Comment: I never like videotutorials (use google if you want them), but here is a nice tutorial to get you up and running: http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: Pointing to a MySQL tutorial....ouch.

Comment: @UmerFarooq - Take a look at [Sun's JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). Then search the web for "_JDBC tutorial_" for lots of other good resources.

Comment: @rfusca, you are right. A database agnostic tutorial would be more suitable. I would have referenced suns (/oracles) page if it would not complicate things with ant and xalan. On the other hand, tutorials should not be referenced here at all, google is our friend

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use a data base management system. One simple approach is to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) with the [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) JDBC driver. SQLite is a popular DBMS for embedded systems and SQLiteJDBC makes it easy to use in Java. This configuration is easy to set up and does not require any data base server to be running; your program will be entirely self-contained.

Comment: Does SQLLiteJDBC library provided by java or I will have to download the library separatly

Comment: I'd favor HSQLDB or H2 if you go with Java. SQLite is better suited for C/C++.

Comment: @UmerFarooq - SQLiteJDBC is a separate library available at the link in my answer.

Comment: @Michael-O - That's a good point. I'd prefer H2 because it has better indexing capabilities (at least according to [this comparison](http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/15-16/HSQLDB-vs-H2)).

Answer (score -2):

If you're describing a database from first principles I'd say you're probably far better off learning to do it the 'file' way first.

Once you've learned how to read and write files if you want (very) simple key/value storage you could use java.util.Properties which provides very simple file read/write operations.

BDB is another "pure java" option that will give you straightforward in-jvm key/value storage without the overhead of learning how to setup/run an external DMBS.